# Creating regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
"shop": null, "amenity": null, "source": null, "public_transport": "stop_position", "religion": null, "history": null, "office": null, "place": null, "natural": null, "phone": null, "repair": null, "barrier": null, "craft": null, "noexit": null, "atm": null, "shape:plan": null,
```

I want to select parts where the values are null like `"shop": null,` `"amenity": null,`.

I tried using expressions `,\s.*:\s"` , `,\s.*null$` and other variations as well but I'm not getting required results.

Comment: Is it a string or a JSON?

Comment: So use a JSON parser instead of regex.

Comment: [Great! Now you have two problems!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a JSON parser, but to answer your question, this regex matches attributes whose value is null:

```
(?<=")[^"]+(?=": null)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/M5Nd7CZBFd)